# PDF using Static Resource generated from REST doesn't display My Image

Tags: pdf, static-resources, images, apexrest

I have different ways in my organization to generate my invoice pdf and attach it to my records. My PDF includes a logo stored in a public StaticResource. It works perfectly everywhere except when I generate my pdf from Apex REST, it doesn't display my logo :

[image]

***Some Code*** :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/invoicereq/*')
global without sharing class InvoiceTemplateController
{
    @HttpGet
    global static void generateInvoiceAttachment()
    {
             ....
             //1. Generate & insert Invoice as an attachment
            PageReference pdf = new Pagereference('/apex/InvoicePDF?id=' + header.Id);
            Blob body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Body = body;
            attachment.Name = 'Invoice ' + header.Name + '.pdf';
            attachment.IsPrivate = false;
            attachment.ParentId = header.Id;
            insert attachment;
            ...
    }
}
```

***HTML***

```
<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyLogo)}" />
```

However if I use my logo as a Document with the same code, it works perfectly.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: And your static resource is public?

Comment: Correct, my static resource is public. Thank you Bachovksi.

Comment: Honestly, not too familiar with REST(yet) but saw another post with similar behavior who suggested using <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyLogo)}"/> vs. <img src> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly set `renderAs` to PDF on the Visualforce page. This must be hardcoded, and not come from a variable.

```
    <apex:page controller="myController" renderAs="PDF" >
        <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyLogo)}" />
    </apex:page>
```

In your controller, call `getContent`, not `getContentAsPDF`:

```
att.body = pdf.getContent();
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm), the content will be "as displayed to a user in a Web browser," which will include your image.